# Facebook API - Friendlist empty result

Tags: facebook, cordova

I'm using Facebook phonegap plugin for my mobile app project. The problem is I get an empty result for friendlist

js

```
facebookConnectPlugin.api("/me/friends?fields=picture,name", ["public_profile", "user_friends"],function(
        response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
    }, function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
    });
```

result

```
2014-08-10 01:41:29.700 TypeOut[590:60b] new permissions (
    installed,
    "public_profile",
    email,
    "user_friends"
)
2014-08-10 01:41:29.701 TypeOut[590:60b] Graph Path = /me/friends?fields=picture,name
2014-08-10 01:41:30.292 TypeOut[590:60b] []
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only return friends that are also using the app

Comment: so how want to retrieve all my facebook friends?

Comment: You can't. It is impossible

Comment: If it is impossible, then how to invite friends to the game?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is a game, use [Request Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.0). If your app is not a game, and on mobile, use [Message Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share).